# Why extending the wire of stepper motor leads to vibration?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, cnc

I'm almost newbie in hobby electronics and I'm trying to extend the wires of my Nema17 stepper motor. (Model: Stepperonline 17HS13-0404S1, 12V, 0.4A) But somehow extension leads to vibration.

It's connected to CNC Shield on Arduino and the main cable (1m length) of stepper motor is integrated to motor, so it doesn't have any connector at the bottom of motor and connected directly to motor but has black terminal (pitch connector) at the end of integrated cable. While it's connected directly to CNC shield, it works well.

I prepared a 4 wires cable with terminals at each side and connecting one side to terminal at the end of motor cable and one side to CNC shield. It seems like cables and terminals are okay. But when I connect motor to CNC shield using this cable, it starts vibrating and seems like cannot step as it should.

I'm sure all wires on extension following the same colors with main cable, so not confusing the sequence of cables.

I am not sure about cable AWG's of the main cable and the extension cable but seems identical and both of them are thin cables like 24 AWG.

What might be the reason for this behaviour and how can I solve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try thicker wires.  Odds are wires are adding a voltage drop.

Comment: Please add to your question: What is the length of the *extension cable*? What does *seems like cannot step as it should* amount to: Doesn't it turn at all, does it seem to miss steps or something else? What is the load?

Comment: You wrote a question, but it contains an affirmation, too: "extending the wire of stepper motor leads to vibration". Yes, this is a fact that you proved experimentally. Probably it happens because steppers draw a lot of current, more than the thin 24 AWG wires can support. If you have a setting where the things work the way you want, I suggest you to experiment changing this settings one at a time. E.g., try thicker wires, or placing the controller near the motor.

Comment: Hello @mguima manufacturer provided main cables are also 24 AWG cables. BTW, main cables are just one meter and the extension cable is 60 cm. Unfortunately I cannot move the controller but will try thicker cables. Thank you.